I got an importerror when i use 'import tesserocr'
On windows 10 64bit, python 3.12.3
I have installed tesseract, it works well, and I have setted up the system path for it, like 'D:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR'
I have successfully installed tesserocr with pip install
but when I use it in python,like
import tesserocr

i got an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tesserocr\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._tesserocr import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _tesserocr:

any one can help me? Thank you !!
I think whether it is a problem of version, but I don't know how to.

did u select the python interpreter correctly ?

first time I see tesserocr - with letter o in name. I know only pytesseract

it seems it searchs some C/C++ module DLL -  so it wasn't installed correctly. Probably it could compile this code during installation. Documentation for tesseroct suggests (for Windows) to download file .whl (which probably already has precompiled module) and install pip install package.whl.

Yes python version 3.12.3  tesseract version 5.3.3

and i solved the problem by using conda to install tesserocr,and it seems works right with no error,but still no working in windows environment

see https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr/issues/332

Did you install windows package as instructed by https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr?tab=readme-ov-file#pip ?
